# Почему в Андроид 4.4 и выше не дает сохранять файлы на карту памяти?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Подскажите пожалуйста почему в андроид, начиная с версии 4.4 не получается записать файлы на microSD карту памяти? Выдает ошибку. Права в манифесте есть, код верный. Под root доступом все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-почему, по кочану.

Google решил, что начиная с Kitkat (Android 4.4) для записи будут доступны только строго определенный набор каталогов на карте памяти.

Подробно [расписано здесь](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/)

Если вкратце, то приложение может создать свой приватный каталог на карте памяти и писать туда, но писать на карту памяти куда угодно запрещено.